# ActiveMQ Artemis blocks on start

Tags: activemq-artemis

Our system is actively using Artemis as a JMS service. Lately, the start of the process blocks for 1 minute by Artemis. We used Jstack to get teh stack trace, and it looks like this:

```
Thread 4515: (state = IN_JAVA)
 - org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.readJournalFile(org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.SequentialFileFactory, org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalFile, org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalReaderCallback) @bci=143, line=461 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.load(org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.LoaderCallback, boolean, org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.Journal$JournalState) @bci=283, line=1728 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.load(java.util.List, java.util.List, org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.TransactionFailureCallback, boolean) @bci=41, line=1365 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.load(java.util.List, java.util.List, org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.TransactionFailureCallback) @bci=5, line=1349 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.AbstractJournalStorageManager.loadMessageJournal(org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.postoffice.PostOffice, org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.PagingManager, org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.transaction.ResourceManager, java.util.Map, java.util.Map, java.util.Set, java.util.List, org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.JournalLoader) @bci=49, line=839 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.loadJournals() @bci=195, line=2585 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.initialisePart2(boolean) @bci=31, line=2352 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.LiveOnlyActivation.run() @bci=58, line=71 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.internalStart() @bci=390, line=635 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.start() @bci=6, line=479 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl.start() @bci=27, line=390 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.server.embedded.EmbeddedJMS.start() @bci=155, line=126 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.javalite.async.Async.start() @bci=28, line=195 (Interpreted frame)
 - app.services.jms.JmsServiceImpl.start() @bci=129, line=107 (Interpreted frame)
 - app.config.AppBootstrap.getInjector() @bci=35, line=60 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.javalite.activeweb.RequestDispatcher.initAppConfig(java.lang.String, org.javalite.activeweb.AppContext, boolean) @bci=51, line=136 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.javalite.activeweb.RequestDispatcher.initApp(org.javalite.activeweb.AppContext) @bci=6, line=71 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.javalite.activeweb.RequestDispatcher.init(javax.servlet.FilterConfig) @bci=134, line=65 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter() @bci=99, line=285 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter() @bci=38, line=266 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(org.apache.catalina.Context, org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.FilterDef) @bci=37, line=108 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart() @bci=148, line=4637 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal() @bci=1235, line=5282 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start() @bci=210, line=150 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(org.apache.catalina.Container) @bci=170, line=754 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(org.apache.catalina.Container) @bci=26, line=730 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(org.apache.catalina.Container) @bci=40, line=734 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(org.apache.catalina.util.ContextName, java.io.File) @bci=1905, line=985 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run() @bci=12, line=1857 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call() @bci=4, line=511 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run() @bci=42, line=266 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=95, line=1149 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=624 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=748 (Interpreted frame)
```

After examining journal files, we see this:

```
du -m --max-depth 1
9721    ./journal
4   ./bindings
0   ./largemessages
1   ./paging
9725    .
```

In other words, the journal is about 10GB while all queues are empty.

Is this the reason for a slow start? How can we avoid this in the future by a  method other than killing all journal files and restarting the process?

EDIT: the above stack trace is the only onewith state = IN_JAVA. All other threads are parked while the process is waiting. The whole wait takes a anywhere from a minute to two. All other threads taken from `jstack` are irrelevant.

Comment: A single stack-trace doesn't really provide anything conclusive.  You'd need to gather and analyze multiple stack-traces to see if the thread remains in the call (and for how long).

Comment: I added a comment. All other threads are irrelevant.

Comment: I'm not really concerned with "other threads".  I'm concerned with what `Thread 4515` is doing *over time*.  You can't see what that thread is doing over time with just a single snapshot.  You need *at least* 2 thread dumps (preferably more).  Then you can see what `Thread 4515` is doing at each snapshot.  Also, you should specify which version of Artemis you're using.

Comment: fair point, I will get you  that info, thanks for directions

Comment: Are you still facing this issue?